# MPMoviePlayerViewController quits while playing the video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video

I am recording the video in my application.  I am saving that video inside Documents directory.  After taking the video if I try to play the video using the following code.  The player opens and quits in one seconds.  However if I Quit and then open my app fresh the video I took earlier is playing.

```
+ (void) playMovieAtURL: (NSURL*) theURL :(id)sender{
NSLog(@"playMovieAtURL");
//senderID = (id *)sender;

if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] doubleValue] >= 3.2) {
    NSLog(@"> 3.2");
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:theURL];

    if (mp)
    {
        // save the movie player object
        //self.moviePlayerViewController = mp;
        //[mp release];
        [sender presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
        //mp.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
        mp.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
        [mp.moviePlayer play];
    }
    [mp release];

} 
else if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] doubleValue] < 3.2) {
    NSLog(@"< 3.2");

    MPMoviePlayerController* theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: theURL];

    theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;

    // Register for the playback finished notification
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver: self
     selector: @selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:)
     name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object: theMovie];

    // Movie playback is asynchronous, so this method returns immediately.
    [theMovie play];
    [theMovie release];


}

}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {  
MPMoviePlayerController *aMoviePlayer = [notification object];  
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self  
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
                                              object:aMoviePlayer];  

// If the moviePlayer.view was added to the view, it needs to be removed  
if ([aMoviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)]) {  
    [aMoviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];  
}  


}
```

This is the code I use for storing the video inside documents.

```
    NSURL *videoURL = [imageInfo objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    NSData *webData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
    self.itsVideoName = fileName;
    [webData writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",dataPath,fileName] atomically:TRUE];
```

Comment: I had this same problem and never found the answer... wonder if this is an SDK bug..which SDK are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the answer after few hours of searching.  This is the code I am using now..

```
  -(IBAction)playMovie:(NSString *) theURL 
{
NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:theURL];
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayerController];

[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
//After putting the following line the problem solved.
moviePlayerController.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;
moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
[moviePlayerController play];
}

- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification
{
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                  name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:moviePlayerController];

[moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
[moviePlayerController release];
}
```

the code moviePlayerController.useApplicationAudioSession = NO; is used to solve this problem.  I am not sure how this problem solved I guess I am using session for audio I guess that was causing problem to this.

Also the code which I originally posted was taking lots of memory like if I opened 2 video it cost 104 mb allocation for me.  This new code was perfect and it is taking only less memory.  Hope this will help for some one..

Comment: Hi i am also facing same problem like u, Is this code works for iOS5

Comment: No it's not works for me and I'm getting url from documents directory like this  The Url is Video%2006-06-12%2011:29:20.mp4 -- file://localhost/ please tell me any problem with reading data from documents directory....

Comment: What is the actual problem you are facing..  The video opens and closes suddenly right?

Comment: Did you add this line moviePlayerController.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;

Comment: are you using any other audio playback in your application?

Comment: I think you have some other audio recording or playback in your app can you please check and say..

Comment: And i am recording a video using device and save that recorded video into document directory this only i do in case of recording..

Comment: Mmm..  are you able to play the recorded video files.  That is by importing the files to you mac.

Comment: Mmm very strange.. does the video recorded from your app or pre recorded videos like.  movie songs..

Comment: The videos are recorded in my app

Comment: Did you implement the exact 2 methods which I have given as asnwer in your application

Answer (score 0):

*NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:theURL];*

should use NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:theURL];

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?